# C# - "The name 'wc' does not exist in the current context" when setting up a webclient from a separate class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webclient

I have an application where all of the code is in a singe file, so I'm looking at tidying it up and create separate classes for some of the re-occurring code instead of having the same code duplicated throughout the application. One such action that's duplicated a lot is setting up a `WebClient` and setting a proxy to do things like download images, check for app updates etc.

I've created a separate 'Proxy.cs' file and added the following code:

```
class Proxy
{
    public static WebClient setProxy()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Proxy = null;

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.useProxy == true)
        {
            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(Properties.Settings.Default.proxyAddress);

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.proxyAuth == true)
            {
                proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.proxyUser, Properties.Settings.Default.proxyPass);
                proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            }

            wc.Proxy = proxy;
        }

        return wc;
    }
}
```

The idea being that when I check for updates, download new images etc, I can just call this class each time to configure the `WebClient/Proxy`. However I cannot seem to get it working. In my main application, I'm calling it like so:

```
Proxy.setProxy();
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(URL);
```

However I get the following error in my main application:

> The name 'wc' does not exist in the current context

I'm still fairly new to C# and can;t work out how to actually get this working. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
WebClient wc = Proxy.setProxy();
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(URL);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Gave it a try and it's working just fine. :)

Comment: Great! Glad it helped.. :)